# How to collect bad rows/records in pyspark while processing?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Hello I'm new to Pyspark, While converting a string column "DOB" in my test.csv file to Date format I had an issue where Pyspark converts the bad records to null values. I'm aware of pyspark's method in handling bad data like , **PERMISSIVE mode, FAILFAST mode, BadRecordPaths**, which collects the bad data while reading the file/input, but is there any possible way to collect the bad records while running a function?

The Code is:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Dob_test").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.option("header", True).csv("./DataSource/test.csv")
df.show()
df.select(to_date(col("DOB"), "MM-dd-yyyy").alias("Date Of Birth")).show()
```

Input:
[DOB input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpaZ7.png)

The Result:

[Result_DOB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPSwD.png)

In Result_DOB, **Date Of Birth column** the date of birth for *NAME3 and NAME 4* is **null**. So I want to collect **NAME3 and NAME4** records as error records/corrupt records while running this line

`df.select(to_date(col("DOB"), "MM-dd-yyyy").alias("Date Of Birth")).show()`

Any possible input would be valuable.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can have another column which keeps the value if it cannot be casted like below

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
tdf=spark.createDataFrame([("Name1","05-25-1994"),("Name2","11-10-1998"),("Name3","et-05-1994"),("Name4","Null")],"name string, DOB string")
tdf.withColumn("corruptDOB",when(to_date(col("DOB"), "MM-dd-yyyy").isNull(),col("DOB"))).select(to_date(col("DOB"), "MM-dd-yyyy").alias("Date Of Birth"),"corruptDOB").show()
```

will give you output like below

```
+-------------+----------+
|Date Of Birth|corruptDOB|
+-------------+----------+
|   1994-05-25|      null|
|   1998-11-10|      null|
|         null|et-05-1994|
|         null|      Null|
+-------------+----------+
```